# The difference between "new Form(A.class)" and "form(A.class)" in PlayFramework?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2

I am using PlayFramework 2.2.1 and I have a question about the difference between `new Form(A.class)` and `form(A.class)`.

In PlayFramework you have to pick values from a specific form in Web page if you want to use these values in your application. And normally I am using the `Form` instance and the `bindFromRequest` method like this:

```
Form<OneForm> f = new Form(OneFrom.class).bindFromRequest();
```

But I also see this code in a certain guiding book:

```
Form<OneForm> f = form(OneForm.class).bindFromRequest();
```

Is there any difference between them? If you have any idea, please teach me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference. Both creates instances of a `Form` that wraps the `OneForm.class` (Check out the [source](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.x/framework/src/play-java/src/main/java/play/data/Form.java#L40-L63)):

```
public static <T> Form<T> form(Class<T> clazz) {
    return new Form<T>(clazz);
}
....
```

So its just a convenience/wrapper method. On another note the `form(..)` method is [deprecated](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/java/play/data/Form.html#form--) in later versions of play (specifically 2.5). So perhaps it's best you stick with the first version if you plan to upgrade the framework to the latest in the future.